# explicit initializtion of template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class with two template arguments with the following constructor:

```
template <class T, class TCompare>
class MyClass {
...
public:
MyClass(TCompare compare);
...
};
```

And I have a structure which overloads operator () for integer comparison:

```
struct IntegerLess {
    bool operator () {const int& a, const int& b) {
       if (a < b)
           return true;
       return false;
    }
};
```

I want to pass this structure as an argument to MyClass constructor. I have tried the following:

```
MyClass<int> myClassObject(IntegerLess());
```

and

```
MyClass<int, typename IntegerLess> myClassObject(IntegerLess());
```

However, both times I have a compile-time error. In the first case

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
```

and in the second case

```
error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Can someone point out what is the right option here? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot deduce *class* template arguments.

Comment: In the second case, you don't need `typename`. That is only for *dependent types* (i.e. a type that exists *inside* a template).

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 is wrong because class template arguments cannot be deduced - you must specify them explicitly (unless they have default values in the class template definition).

Number 2 just has an extra `typename` which shouldn't be there. The correct syntax is:

```
MyClass<int, IntegerLess> myClassObject(IntegerLess());
```

And in case `IntegerLess` is your actual code and not a mock you produced to simplify the question, consider using `std::less<int>` instead, which does precisely what your class does. You could even make that a default template argument for the class, like this:

template >
class MyClass
{
public:
  explicit MyClass(TCompare compare = TCompare());
  // ... the rest as before
};

If you do that, you will then be able to use it in simplified form:

```
MyClass<int> myClassObject;
```